# iTextSharp 7 wrapping and no wrapping

Tags: itext, itext7

Is it possible to manage wrapping of text?
I have a long string, longer than a cell, in a paragraph. If it is in form "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", will be displayed on a line (row) of text. But if it is in  "ABC DEFGH IJKLM" form, it is wrapped in two lines. How could be forced to stay on one line?

Comment: Have you tried using a non-breaking space?

Comment: I know the non-breaking space in HTML (&nbsp;). How is it for iText?

Comment: If you refer to '\u00a0', it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you should provide some code to illustrate your issue. In my experience the string is not wrapped if the cell is big enough. And if it is not big enough, what do you really expect? Shall the string continue into the next cell? Or shall it be cut?

Comment: Well, first of all, I have expected to have no wrapping. Next, an option to cut and an option to expand horizontally to the next or to the previous cell, depending on the alignment.

Comment: *I have expected to have no wrapping* - That is an interesting expectation... a paragraph after all usually is a multi-line entity, so wrapping is a fairly natural feature... *an option to expand horizontally to the next or to the previous cell, depending on the alignment* - what about the cell border line you draw across?

Comment: Sorry, for clarification purposes, I would like the cell to expand. Anyway, the no wrapping idea comes out of many pages on the Internet saying it wouldn't wrap if no wrapping spaces are used. I don't know if it did, it doesn't do this anymore ...

Comment: Please, clarify what means `Have you tried using a non-breaking space?` in iText case, though.

Comment: I indeed meant the '\u00a0'. But i also misunderstood your question. As you said it worked with strings without a space character, it should have worked with that char, too. As it turned out, though, it didn't even work in the former case...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a comment the OP clarified

> I would like the cell to expand. Anyway, the no wrapping idea comes out of many pages on the Internet saying it wouldn't wrap if no wrapping spaces are used. I don't know if it did, it doesn't do this anymore ...

The iText 7 `Table` with its default `TableRenderer` renderer class only supports fixed column widths which can be given by

- a fixed table width and a single integer, the number of columns,
- a fixed table width and an array of relative column widths, or
- an array of absolute column widths.

Thus, what those *many pages on the Internet* say, does not seem possible.

---

That been said, the iText 7 architecture allows to set a custom next renderer. Thus, it might be possible to introduce a certain amount of dynamic behavior, in particular some automatic cell resizing, if you implement a table renderer to do so.

Such a custom renderer is likely to run into problems, though, whenever code makes use of the `ILargeElement` interface `Table` implements because then the first cells will have to be layout'ed before all cell contents are known.